# Show the encrypted string for the user ‘ironman’ from the file /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, centos7

I created a user and I want to encrypt a string for that user from the /etc/shadow.
How can I go about doing that

Comment: Your question does not make sense as written. Were you maybe wanting to recover the encrypted password for the user?

Comment: yea thats it but I need the encrypted string for the user

Answer (score 3):

Hashing the user password is one way operation, you can hash a plain text password and receive a hash.

However from a given hash, you cannot restore the original password in plain text.

Also if two passwords have the same hash, they are same, but because of [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), different hashes does not guarantee passwords are different.

Having that said, to see the hash of a given plain text password, you may

- create a test user (`sudo useradd test`),
- then change their password (`sudo passwd test`),
- check the hash that was written in `/etc/shadow` (`sudo grep test /etc/shadow`)
- and finally delete the newly created user for security reasons (`sudo userdel test`)

Better do that on an offline server so the short time when test user exists with a known or easy password cannot be used to compromise the system.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  If you have getent -

```
 sudo getent shadow username | cut -f2 -d:
```

- Sudo - Run as root - we need to be root to read shadow password.
- getent shadow username - gets line in shadow password for username
- cut -f 2 -d:" gets the second field in the tab delimited file, which is the encrypted password.

If you don't have getent you can affect the same using grep

```
sudo grep "^username:" /etc/shadow  | cut -f2 -d":"
```

The idea here is to use grep to get the required line which has a similar effect to getent.  the "^" before the username means that the line needs to start with username.   The ":" at the end is the field delimiter.   This is so if you have multiple similar users, only 1 will match.  (ie myusername and username4me won't match).

Answer (score 0):

glibc has a program for that:

```
getent shadow ironman
```

Outputs a delimited string that includes the hashed password. Needs to be run privileged.  Works even if the user in not in files and is in something like LDAP, per nsswitch.conf.

Beware that hashed passwords can be cracked eventually. Change any password whose hash could have been seen by anyone other than the user who set it and system administrators.